# Can we add a scroll view inside UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling

I have requirement where I have to show some images which are differentiated according to Groups they belong to. I have used a table view to view images listed under groups. User has to scroll horizontally to view more images in a particular group.
Can we add a scroll view to tableview row to allow user to scroll list of images horizontally?
I searched a bit, some comments say its not allowed in apple's HIG some comments say 
[You can add a UIScrollView to a UITableViewCell and as long as you set the contentSize property of the UIScrollView correctly then the UIScrollView will scroll correctly in the horizontal axis](http://theexciter.com/articles/touches-and-uiscrollview-inside-a-uitableview.html)

May I get any confirmation on this ??
Or any alternative approach to achieve horizontal and vertical scrolling for different data without using tableview

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is definitively possible and reasonable.

Here is an **excellent tutorial** by *Felipe Laso* that explains it step by step:

[How To Make An Interface With Horizontal Tables Like The Pulse News App: Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1)

[How To Make An Interface With Horizontal Tables Like The Pulse News App: Part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2)

BTW, the approach described in that tutorial is way more efficient than adding a UIScrollview to each cell.

Comment: Do you have any sources proving that nested `UITableView`s are more efficient than `UIScrollView`s? I dont' see anything in the links you provided.

Comment: UITableView is a UIScrollView subclass that is more efficient because it can reuse cells. In a scroll view you would have lots of sub views that all consume memory at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can add scrollView in tableView.

```
 UIScrollView *scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];            
 [cell.contentView addSubview:scrollView];
```

Now you can set properties for scroll view accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is possible.  A UIScrollView inside a UITableCellView will work fine - the HIG says no, probably because it'll be hard to use.  The user would have to accuratley scroll either up/down, or left/right and it might be annoying.  Shouldn't take long to knock together a quick test.

I have an app with 2 scrollviews - one that allows horizontal scroll, and then inside that another scrollview which allows vertical scroll.  The idea is that the user can flick up/down a page, then also flick left/right across pages.

It's not that nice to use, but it's what my client wanted ;)

To make a UIScrollView only respond to horizontal or vertical scroll is all about setting the correct contentSize.  Hope this is some help.

Comment: The HIG was made to be broken.