# Display multiple images in Tableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, imageview, uitableview

How to display multiple images in a single cell on clicking forward and back button like shown in below image.

[image]

Comment: Replace the image on button click? You just need a custom tablecellview and some basic objective c knowledge

Comment: Use custom tableview cell.

Comment: @Pat_Morita How to get popup on clicking that image

Comment: add scrollview with paging in your customcell. please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645779/can-we-add-a-scroll-view-inside-uitableviewcell  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185446/horizontal-uiscrollview-inside-custom-uitableviewcell-using-ib-storyboard-no     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273250/add-uiscrollview-with-paging-to-existing-uiviewcontroller    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740425/ios-how-to-do-proper-paging-in-uiscrollview

Comment: To open a popover either work with storyboard and a popover segue or instantinate your own popoverViewController

Comment: Customize the table view cell and use any third party libraries https://cocoapods.org/?q=gallery for easy handling of gallery

Answer (score 2):

I guess your table array will look like:

```
[
    {
        price   : "$ 000",
        adress  : "adress",
        size    : "size",
        imagesArray : [
                    {
                        imageName : "name",
                        image  : "image"
                    }
                  ]
    }
]
```

Use **collection view** in table view cell, and enable pagination for collection view. Pass images array to collection view

or

if use image view only in table view cell, you should maintain position of the images. So just create a mutable **position array** with table array count like table array as 3 values, and the position array should be like [0,0,0]. Initially, 0th index will be visible. so given values are 0.

in **cellForIndex** method:

```
NSArray * imageArray =[NSArray new];
imageArray = [[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imagesArray"]

NSInteger imageIndex = [positionArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

cell.imageView.image = [imageArray objectAtindex:imageIndex] valueForKey:@"image"]
```

Set **indexpath** as a tag for arrow buttons.

if you click right arrow in 1st index of table view, In target method, get index from tag and increase value at 1st index value of position array. Now reload table view or particular cell.